# What is the particular solution for $ y''+2y'=2x+5-e^{-2x}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How is the particular solution for $y''+2y'=2x+5-e^{-2x}$ be the following?

$$y_p = Ax^2 + Bx + Cxe^{-2x}$$

Shouldn't it be $y_p = Ax + B + Cxe^{-2x}$?

Anything of degree one should be in the form $Ax + B$, and $2x+5$ is in degree one and not squared... I just don't get it.

Comment: I hope you noticed that, setting z = y', you have a much simpler problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

The particular solution is of the form:

$$y_p = a x + b x^2 + c x e^{-2x}$$

We have to take $a  + b x$ and multiply by $x$ and multiply $e^{-2x}$ by $x$ because we already have a constant in homogeneous and also have $e^{-2x}$ in homogeneous.

Comment: That's already written in the question. OP is asking very specific questions about why it's that as opposed to his/her own idea of a particular solution.

Comment: @Amzoti Is it because there is a constant already in yc and since that matches B, that would cause a glitch? Wouldn't I have to just multiply B only by x? Why Ax as well? There is no term like Ax in yc.

Comment: If you only use an $x$ term, what would happen to it when you take the second derivative? We need to have an $x$ remain after taking the 2nd derivative because it shows up in the particular solution. We do not know apriori if it annihilates, so have to choose the next higher power to make sure it does not, so we multiply the 'entire' quantity $(a + bx)$ by $x$. Choose $y_p = ax+b + cxe^{-2x}$ and substitute back into the ODE and see what it gives. This becomes an intuition thing after you do a few like that. See: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx

Comment: Needs a TU-UV +1

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks! :-)

Comment: @Amzoti: ${}{}{}{}{}+$

Comment: @B.S.: Ditto your nice solution :-) +1 Very quiet weekend on MSE! Suspect the same next week! Have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

Using [The Annihilator Method](http://www.utdallas.edu/dept/abp/PDF_Files/DE_Folder/Annihilator_Method.pdf), we have:

$$P(D)y=D^3(D+2)^2y=0$$ so the probable suitable general solution is: $$y(x)=C_1+C_2x+C_3x^2+C_4xe^{-2x}+C_5e^{-2x}$$ Now pick the $y_p$.

Comment: Sounds like a "scary" method! +1

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you wanted to find the particular solution to $y'=x$. The answer is obviously $x^2$: notice that the degree of $x^2$ is one greater than $x$. You can't assume the particular solution will have degree $\le$ the degree of the inhomogeneous part on the right-hand side of the original ODE.

As for why the constant is left out of the particular solution form, it is redundant. Since there is no term with just "$y$" on the left-hand side, only derivatives of $y$, and constant part will be killed off and so it doesn't need to be considered.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the "lowest" derivative in the differential equation is $y'$. If your solution was to be chosen then the $Ax+B$ will become $A$. Thus the highest degree polynomial expression you can get with your solution is a constant. Essentially this means you will be lacking an $x$ term on the LHS. This is what the $x^2$ term in $y_p = Ax^2 + Bx + Cxe^{-2x}$ does. It provides the $x$ term and is why
$$y_p = Ax^2 + Bx + Cxe^{-2x}$$
and **not**
$$y_p = Ax + B + Cxe^{-2x}$$

Comment: Is it because there is a constant already in yc and since that matches B, that would cause a glitch? Wouldn't I have to just multiply B only by x? Why Ax as well? There is no term like Ax in yc.

Comment: @JoMo You haven't defined yc. Do you mean yp?

Comment: No, I mean yc, complementary function.

Comment: @JoMo The constant in $y_c$ is of no effect on $y_p$. We could have included a constant in $y_p$ too, but it wouldn't make a difference. To address your other concern, you correctly point out that $2x+5$ is not squared. However, we are taking derivatives so we need a squared term in $y_p$ to get a degree one term since exponents decrease when we take derivatives.

Comment: I was taught that if there is a duplicate term of yp in yc, we would need to multiply that term by x. Does that apply here to the Ax + B?